# How to construct a xml file from dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dataset, resultset

I have the query which gives me the status value , where the query output is stored in the `ResultSet`,

```
IResultSet resultSet = dbManager.Provider.GetData(dataOperation);
```

How can i construct the xml of following type , with the value node data in the xml tag should be set with value in the ResultSet

```
<Chart editMode='1' bgColor='FFFFFF' bgAlpha='0' showBorder='0' upperLimit='1000' lowerLimit='0' numberPrefix='$' gaugeRoundRadius='5' chartBottomMargin='30' ticksBelowGauge='0' placeTicksInside='0' showGaugeLabels='0' pointerOnTop='1' pointerRadius='14' chartLeftMargin='25' chartRightMargin='30' majorTMColor='868F9B' majorTMHeight='10' majorTMThickness='2' pointerBgAlpha='0' pointerBorderThickness='2' majorTMNumber='0' minorTMNumber='0' showToolTip='0' decimals='0'>

    <colorRange> 
        <color minValue='0' maxValue='100' code='F6BD0F' />
    </colorRange>

    <value>665</value>

    <trendpoints>
        <point value='350' fontcolor='FF4400' useMarker='0' dashed='1' dashLen='1' dashGap='3' markerRadius='5' color='FF654F' alpha='100' thickness='2'/>
        <point value='800' fontcolor='FF4400' useMarker='0' dashed='1' dashLen='1' dashGap='3' markerRadius='5' color='8BBA00' alpha='100' thickness='2'/>
    </trendpoints>

    <annotations>
        <annotationGroup id='Grp1' showBelow='1'>
            <annotation type='rectangle' x='2' y='2' toX='445' toY='95' radius='10' fillColor='D6E0F6' fillAngle='90' borderColor='868F9B' borderThickness='2'/>
        </annotationGroup>
    </annotations>

    <styles>
        <definition>
            <style name='ValueFont' type='Font' bgColor='333333' size='10' color='FFFFFF'/>
            <style name='RectShadow' type='Shadow' strength='3'/>
        </definition>
        <application>
            <apply toObject='VALUE' styles='valueFont'/>
            <apply toObject='Grp1' styles='RectShadow' />
        </application>
    </styles>
</Chart>
```

Comment: I am trying to implement something like this  StringBuilder xmlData=new StringBuilder();
  //Generate the chart element
  xmlData.Append("<chart caption='Factory Output report' subCaption='By Quantity' pieSliceDepth='30' showBorder='1' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix=' Units'>");,But for constructing value node i have confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if:

```
IResultSet resultSet = dbManager.Provider.GetData(dataOperation);
```

is actually a dataset object, does not seem like...

in ADO.NET Syste.Data.DataSet object has a method to write the XML file of the contained data, see here:

[DataSet.WriteXml Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx)

calling that method you are ok and you can then inspect the generated `XML` file.

in your question's title you are asking how to create an XML from dataset not from an `IResultSet`

Comment: DataSet has GetXML() method as well. If mahesh is OK with standard dataset XML structure, of course.

Comment: Can i implement something like, read the existing xml file from xml reader , then update only value node , with the value which i get from resultset

Answer (score 2):

If you are implementing your own XML structure, it's worth using Linq to XML instead of using StringBuilder.

Check out [this article](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx), it should help.